# debian install .deb package with dependencies

Tags: debian, package-management

How do I install `g++-10` from Debian 11 (https://packages.debian.org/testing/devel/g++-10) on Debian 10?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to Debian 11 already then? I do use it on all servers. -1 for no clarification.

Comment: Debian 11 will be officially released this weekend, and there won’t be any significant change to it between now and then. Upgrading is the easiest way to get GCC 10.

Comment: Wait for the upgrade instructions???

Answer (score 2):

Installing package from differnt branch is extremely unrecommended, because they may be linked to newer version of libraries. You may install one of your branch. Anyway, if you still want to install it, download it and install it with

```
sudo apt-get install ./g++-10_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb
```

`apt` will resolve all dependencies, if possible, that is.

Do at your own risk